# Split file of lines multiple files with PHP

Tags: php

I have one file with 5000 rows and i want to split it to multiple files with ~200 rows each file. First file contains header row and that row needs to be placed those separate files as well.

After run i have 25 files (fileofrows_1.csv ... fileofrows_25.csv) but first file contains 402 rows. Why?

Here is the code i used:

```
<?php
$filecount = 1;
$rowcount = 0;
$headerrow = '';
$filename = 'fileofrows';
$newfilename = $filename . "_" . $filecount . ".csv";
$splitvalue = 200;
$initheader = true;

if ($file = fopen($filename . ".csv", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);

        if($initheader){
            // Write header row to file
            $headerrow = $line;
            file_put_contents ( $newfilename, trim($headerrow) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            $initheader = false;            
        }else{
            // Write content row to file
            file_put_contents ( $newfilename , trim($line) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            $rowcount++;
        }

        if($rowcount === $splitvalue){
            // Switch file
            $newfilename = $filename . "_" . $filecount . ".csv";
            // Write header row to new file
            file_put_contents ( $newfilename, trim($headerrow) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            $filecount++;
            $rowcount = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `$newfilename` before you increment `$filecount`.

```
if($rowcount === $splitvalue){
    // Increment counter before setting new name
    $filecount++;
    // Switch file
    $newfilename = $filename . "_" . $filecount . ".csv";
    // Write header row to new file
    file_put_contents ( $newfilename, trim($headerrow) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    $rowcount = 0;
}
```

You should try to reduce code duplication as it makes it harder to read. I have done a small refactor of your code.

```
$fileCount = 1;
$rowCount = 0;
$headerRow = '';
$fileName = 'fileofrows';
$newFileName = null;
$splitValue = 200;
$initHeader = true;

function setFileName($num) {
    $newFileName = $filename . "_" . $fileCount . ".csv";
}

function writeLine($row) {
    file_put_contents ($newFileName, trim($row) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}

function writeHeader() {
    writeLine($headerRow);
    $initHeader = false;
}

function writeRow($row) {
    writeLine($row);
    $rowCount++;
}

if ($file = fopen($fileName . ".csv", "r")) {
    setFileName();
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);

        if($initHeader){
            $headerRow = $line;
            writeHeader($file);
        }else{
            writeRow($line);
        }

        if($rowCount === $splitValue){
            $fileCount++;
            setFileName();
            writeHeader()
            $fileCount++;
            $rowCount = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```